# validation issue with empty dropdowns

Tags: php, html

Im trying to add validation to my form and this input is giving me trouble. what Id like it to do is on a new form the input dropdown would be set to select($text_select)and that would be value ="" then if they try to submit the validation rule would go into affect. None of this happening currently and Im not sure why.
VIEW:

[working input with $text_select and validation]

```
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></label>
                        <select name="campaign_owner" id="campaign_owner" >
                          <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                          <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" <?php echo ($campaign_owner == $user['username']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option>

                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <?php if ($error_campaign_owner) { ?>
                        <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_campaign_owner; ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

[messed up input]

```
   <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                  <label class="control-label" for="input-active"><?php echo $entry_active; ?></label>
                  <select name="campaign_active" id="input-active" class="form-control">
                  <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>                      
                  <?php if ($campaign_active ) { ?>  

                    <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
                    <option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>
                    <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>                    
                  </select>                            
                  <?php if (isset($error_campaign_active)) { ?>
                    <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_campaign_active; ?></label>
                  <?php } ?>                   
                </div>
```

CONTROLLER:

[form function]

```
if (isset($this->error['campaign_active'])) {
            $data['error_campaign_active'] = $this->error['campaign_active'];
        } else {
            $data['error_campaign_active'] = '';
        }
```

[validation function]

```
 if (($this->request->post['campaign_active']) == ''){
                $this->error['campaign_active'] = $this->language->get('error_campaign_active');
            }
```

Comment: in your view, if `$campaign` is not empty, it will not go into the inner `if` and if `$campaign` is empty, then it will not execute the inner `if`

Comment: OK I updated the view code to show what I was trying before. I have a few other drop downs that are dynamic and they work just fine. I tried using the same format but it is not working